# Elementary Set Theory, cofinal subset, cofinality, ordinal, totally ordered set problem

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

> **Definition 1.** Let $\langle u,<\rangle$ be totally ordered set, $v\subset u$. $v$ is cofinal subset of $u$ means that for all $a\in u$, there exist $b\in v$ ($a\le b$).
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $\alpha,\beta$ be ordinals. $\beta$ is cofinal of $\alpha$ means that there exist a cofinal subset of $\alpha$, $v$, and $\langle \beta,\in\rangle\cong\langle v,\in \rangle$.
>
> **Definition 3.**
>   Let $\alpha$ be ordinal. $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ means that $$\min\{\beta\mid \beta\text{ is a ordinal and there exist a cofinal subset of } \alpha, v,\text{ and } \langle \beta,\in\rangle\cong\langle v,\in\rangle))\}$$

**Question 1.**
If $\alpha$ be limit ordinal, then $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\alpha)=\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$.

**Question 2.**
Let $\alpha,\beta$ be ordinals. $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha+\beta)=\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$.

I tried to solve it like blow,

about question 1. 
$\alpha\le\aleph_\alpha$ and $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\le\alpha$ hence $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\le\aleph_\alpha$......[*1]
$\operatorname{cf}(\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)) = \operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$　and [*1] hence $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\alpha)\ge\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$

about question 2.
$\alpha\le\alpha+\beta$ hence $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\le\operatorname{cf}(\alpha+\beta)$

Is it correct? and how can I show the invesrses of inequalities.
Please help me.

Comment: Cofinality is not an increasing function. More specifically, $\omega_1<\omega_1+\omega$, but $\DeclareMathOperator{\cf}{cf}\cf(\omega_1)=\omega_1>\omega=\cf(\omega_1+\omega)$.

Comment: I understand  cofinality is not increasing .

Comment: i could solve problem.

Comment: Q2 is false when  $0=\beta \ne \alpha.$

Answer (score 3):

Your approach implicitly assumes that cofinality is a non-decreasing function, which as you know is false.

Here’s an extended HINT for the second question, which I think is a little easier than the first. Once you’ve worked your way through that problem, we can worry about the other problem in a separate question if you’re still stuck on it.

Let $u$ be a cofinal subset of $\beta$.

- Let $v=\{\alpha+\xi:\xi\in u\}$. Show that $v$ is cofinal in $\alpha+\beta$, and that $\langle v,\in\rangle\cong\langle u,\in\rangle$.
- Deduce that $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha+\beta)\le\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$.

Now let $u$ be a cofinal subset of $\alpha+\beta$, and let $v=\{\xi:\alpha+\xi\in u\}$.

- Show that $v$ is cofinal in $\beta$.
- Show that $\operatorname{cf}(v)=\operatorname{cf}(\{\alpha+\xi:\xi\in v\})\le\operatorname{cf}(u)$.
- Deduce that $\operatorname{cf}(\beta)\le\operatorname{cf}(\alpha+\beta)$.

Answer (score 2):

I actually slightly disagree with Brian re: easiness; I'll give a sketch of a solution to problem 1.

The principle behind the solution is what I think of as "cofinal in cofinal = cofinal": if I have

- an ordinal $\alpha$,
- a cofinal embedding $h$ of an ordinal $\beta$ into $\alpha$ (that is, a sequence $\alpha_\eta$ ($\eta<\beta$) of ordinals $<\alpha$ which is cofinal in $\alpha$ - think of $\alpha_\eta$ as $h(\eta))$,
- and a cofinal embedding $g$ of an ordinal $\gamma$ into $\beta$ (that is, a sequence $\beta_\theta$ ($\theta<\gamma$) of ordinals $<\beta$ which is cofinal in $\beta$ - think of $\beta_\theta$ as $g(\theta))$,

then I can combine these to get a cofinal embedding of $\gamma$ in $\alpha$: look at $h\circ g: \gamma\rightarrow\alpha$. Put another way, "thinning ordinals out" doesn't change their cofinality. Note that in particular, this means $cf(\beta)\le cf(\alpha)$, and it's not too hard to show that the converse also holds as long as $h$ is order-preserving.

So in problem (1), we want to find a cofinal, order-preserving embedding of $\alpha$ into $\aleph_\alpha$. Can you think of one? (HINT: $\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, . . .$)

Comment: ℵα = { ℵβ ∣ β<α } so i can find order-preserving embedding of α into ℵα .

Comment: Your hint means that in the case of β is cofinal of α then cf(β)≤cf(α)?

Comment: @tarou Yes, that's the cofinal order-preserving embedding of $\alpha$ into $\aleph_\alpha$ I was thinking of. And the point of the rest of the answer is a bit stronger: it's that if $\beta$ has a cofinal order-preserving embedding into $\alpha$, then their cofinalities are equal!

Comment: i could solve question1 using your hint.

Comment: I didnt use the condition, α is an limit ordinal.

Comment: i need to use this condition for proof?

Comment: @tarou If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then the embedding $\alpha\rightarrow\aleph_\alpha: \beta\mapsto\aleph_\beta$ is *not cofinal* in $\aleph_\alpha$! Ex: take $\alpha=\omega+1$. Then you get $\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, . . . , \aleph_\omega$, which is not cofinal in $\aleph_{\omega+1}$. (Also, really I ought to be writing e.g. "$\omega_n$" instead of "$\aleph_n$," but oh well.)

Comment: I understand. if α isn't a limit ordinal embeding is not cofinal in ℵα.

Comment: { ℵβ ∣ β<α } is not cofinal, because ℵβ  + 1 ∈ℵ(ω+1) , and for all x (ℵβ  + 1 < x ) x is not in { ℵβ ∣ β<α }.

Comment: ℵα = { ℵβ ∣ β<α } is not correct, <α ,∈>=<{ ℵβ ∣ β<α },∈>.

Comment: thank you . i could solve all.